# I need help when I try to upload an image CodeIgnite4

Tags: file-upload, codeigniter-4

I need help when I try to upload an image

I get this error and I don't understand why
`avatar is not a valid uploaded file.`

my code in controller

rules:

```
'avatar' => [
                'rules' => 'required|uploaded[avatar]|max_size[avatar,1024]|ext_in[avatar,jpg,jpeg,png]',

                'errors' => [
                    'required' => lang('Core.Auth.Error.required'),
                    ]
            ],
```

upload:

```
if (!$this->validate($rules)) {
            $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
        } else {

                $avatar = $this->request->getFile('avatar');
                   $newName = $avatar->getRandomName(); 
                   $avatar->move(WRITEPATH.'uploads', $newName);
                   $filepath = base_url()."/selfie/".$newName;
```

my php.ini

upload_max_filesize = 1G

post_max_size = 1G

memory_limit = 1G

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error

Comment: @parttimeturtle the problem is that he can't give us the full stack trace error because CodeIgniter doesn't give further details

Comment: Thx all,  the problem came from  enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From CodeIgniter documentation:

> The **uploaded** rule fails if the name of the parameter does not match the name of any uploaded files.

The exact error message you posted will appear if this rule cannot be satisfied

Double check your HTML `<input>` tag and make sure that both `name` attribute of this tag and the name passed to `uploaded` rule are the same, e.g.:

```
// In the HTML
<input type="file" name="avatar">

// In the controller
$this->validate([
    'avatar' => 'required|uploaded[avatar]|max_size[avatar,1024]|ext_in[avatar,jpg,jpeg,png]'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use this code in your controller for image upload

//set validation
$validateImage = $this->validate([
     'file' => [
            'uploaded[feature_image]',
            'mime_in[feature_image, image/JPG, image/jpg, image/jpeg, 
            image/JPEG, image/png, image/PNG]',
            'max_size[feature_image, 4096]',
     ],
]);

$replaceArray = array('(',')',' ');

$fileName = str_replace($replaceArray,'',$_FILES['feature_image']['name']);

$img = $this->request->getFile('feature_image');

//check validation and image upload                 
if ($validateImage && ! $img->hasMoved()) 
{
    $img->move(HOTEL_MEDIA_ORIGINAL_PATH,$fileName,true);
} 
else 
{
    echo $this->validator->getErrors('file')['file']);
}
```